# Google Maps API v3 - fitBounds after multiple geocoder requests

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What I want to do is load a bunch of addresses using AJAX and JSON, find out the latitude and longitude of each address, put markers on the map and then use `fitBounds()` to zoom in so that all markers are visible. Sounds simple.

I've got most of that down packed but my issue is the `fitBounds()` part.

Basically what seems to be occurring is while looping through each of the addresses and finding the latitude and longitude, it seems to load the `fitBounds()` function below the loop.

So it's calling `fitBounds()` but doesn't have anything in the `marker_bounds` array yet. I would have thought it would have finished looping before getting to the `fitBounds()` function but I guess the `geocoder.geocode()` function must cause it to continue loading the rest of the JavaScript while it determines a latitude and longitude.

My code is below:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker_bounds = [];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    

$.post('addresses.php', function(data) {

    var next_filter = '';           
    for(var x=0;x<data.addresses.length;x++) {

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data.addresses[x].address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                marker_bounds.push(latLng);             
            }

        });             
    }

    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for ( var i = 0; i < marker_bounds.length; i++ ) {
       latlngbounds.extend(marker_bounds[i]);
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); 

}, 'json');
```

Is there a function that I can call after all geocoding has been completed?

Comment: I've been doing more digging and it seems the geocode method makes an asynchonous call which would explain why my function is finishing and returned long before the geocoder is done. Is there a way to determine when all geocode methods have completed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've learned.

1. The geocode method makes an asynchonous call so the page that the geocode method is in will finish long before the geocoder is done looking up addresses during that process.
2. You need to call a function (`addressBounds`) after the geocode method is run and count how many addresses it has geocoded (`address_count`).
3. Each time the `addressBounds` function is called, check to see if all addresses have been looked up (`if (total_addresses == address_count)`), then run the `fitBounds()` function.

My final code

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markerBounds = [];  

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}   
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){

    $.post('addresses.php', function(data) {

        var total_addresses = data.addresses.length;            
        var address_count = 0;
        for(var x=0;x<total_addresses;x++) {    

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data.addresses[x].address }, function(results, status) {

                address_count++;        

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    infowindow.setContent(address);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());                      
                    addressesBounds(total_addresses, address_count, myLatLng);  

                }

            });

        }

    }, 'json');

});

function addressesBounds(total_addresses, address_count, myLatLng) {

    markerBounds.push(myLatLng);

    // make sure you only run this function when all addresses have been geocoded
    if (total_addresses == address_count) {
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for ( var i = 0; i < markerBounds.length; i++ ) {
           latlngbounds.extend(markerBounds[i]);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: And there is no possibility to do everything synchronously?

Comment: @RodrigoMoreno I haven't rebuilt this code since so I can't answer that one. I'm sure they may have made improvements between then and now.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way of doing it to define your bounds object in global scope at the *top* with the other variables, and then construct it with each result as it's found (inside the geocoder callback).

Basically, everything you want to do with callback data needs to be in the callback or a function triggered by the callback (as you found). But in this case you don't need a separate function. The browser should store up all the `fitBounds` operations and do only the last one.

```
var latLng = new google.Maps.LatLng(
                          results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                          results[0].geometry.location.lng());
marker_bounds.push(latLng);
latlngbounds.extend(latLng);
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

If necessary (because your browser is fast enough to do the `fitBounds` for every address), you could keep track of how many results have actually been returned in another variable, like your `address_count`, and test whether you have all the results before doing the `fitBounds`. That is, your subsidiary function can be incorporated into the geocoder callback.

```
var latLng = new google.Maps.LatLng(
                          results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                          results[0].geometry.location.lng());
marker_bounds.push(latLng);
latlngbounds.extend(latLng);
address_count++;
if (address_count == data.addresses.length) map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the following is not strictly related, but I've been struggling with this for quite a while, and I think it's worth sharing.
After rendering multiple direction requests with DirectionsRenderer, the map was focused usually on the result of the last render command, despite the fact that I issued map.fitBounds after issuing the last render command with a bounding box to include all the direction request results in the viewport. The behaviour was not deterministic, sometimes the viewport was focused on the entire map, sometimes on the last direction request result. The solution was to set the preserveViewport:true for the renderer, so it never changes the focus of the map after displaying a direction request result, so now I'm able to change the focus with the fitbounds.