# How to center and zoom multiple markers on Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the following code:

```
 var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        // var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.733833,0.351563);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.590875,-2.279663);
        // var latlng = new Array (new google.maps.LatLng (52.537,-2.061), new google.maps.LatLng (52.564,-2.017));
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        addPostCode('EX4 5SP');
        addPostCode('EX16 6LH');
        addPostCode('M1 2AP');

}
```

I found some example how to achieve this In the following code: [Google MAP API v3: Center & Zoom on displayed markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818984/google-map-api-v3-center-zoom-on-displayed-markers) to achieve this, the following code is used.

```
// map: an instance of GMap3
// latlng: an array of instances of GLatLng
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
latlng.each(function(n){
   latlngbounds.extend(n);
});
map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

The problem is that I need to use Postcodes to display the location on the map. Is is possible to create an array of instances of GLatLng from a postcode and then use the above code to zoom and center the multiple markers on map?

Comment: GLatLng is from Google Maps API v2, not v3.  You mean an array of instances of google.maps.LatLng I hope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API v3 - fitBounds after multiple geocoder requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336405/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-after-multiple-geocoder-requests)

Answer (score 3):

GClientGeocoder can take a postal code and return a GLatLng: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/JN8OW5Tyaws.

For centering multiple markers, see [Find center of multiple locations in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634199/find-center-of-multiple-locations-in-google-maps)

Yes this is V2-- the GLatLng threw me.  The same functionality exists in V3:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: GClientGeocoder is from the deprecated Google Maps API v2, @Roman's using API v3 (despite his misleading reference to GLatLng)

Comment: I have solved my problem of converting postcodes to lat/long by calling the following url in ColdFusion: <cfhttp url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#postcode#&sensor=false" result="myResult">
    <cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(myResult.filecontent)>

    <cfset lat= #cfData.results[1].geometry.location.lat# >
    <cfset lng= #cfData.results[1].geometry.location.lng# > This  returns the json with lat/long.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> //locationsColl      containts list of co ordinates

```
var latlng = [];
_.forEach(locationsColl, function (address) {
    latlng.push(address);
});

var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
_.forEach(latlng,function (n) {
    latlngbounds.extend(n);
});
// center map to central point between markers
map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
// set zoom to fit all coord
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```